# I don't know why he doesn't recognize the VARCHAR date type in mariadb

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb

I get this error for the next procedure

> ERROR 4161 (HY000): Unknown data type: 'p_name'

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_createUser`
(
    IN p_name VARCHAR(45),
    IN p_username VARCHAR(45),
    IN p_password VARCHAR(45)
)
BEGIN
    if ( select exists (select 1 from user where username = p_username) ) THEN
     
        select 'Username Exists !!';
     
    ELSE
insert into user
        (
            name,
            username,
            password
        )
        values
        (
            p_name,
            p_username,
            p_password
        );
     
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: Perhaps you don't need to set delimiters - what ide are you using? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=9882d234761ac0482c465bdaedfab333